# what kind of measure or column will use here

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

[Please refer to the below image. I want to create a stacked column chart but I don't have a column that includes 0-30, 30-60, 60-90, etc. How did I put this range on X-axis?
And I didn't understand what kind of measure is used for "LAST 3 MONTH average" & "LAST 12 MONTH average ".
Can you please assist me with the same? ]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEnoa.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is Microsoft documentation on using grouping and binning features in Power BI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning

You can create a measure for last 3 month average like this:

```
3 Month Average = CALCULATE(
                      AVERAGE(Table[value]),
                      FILTER(Table,
                          Table[date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()-3),DAY(TODAY()))
                      )
                  )
```

Comment: Hi @strickly Funk,
 I tried above mentioned DAX measure but it didn't work. It gave me an error i.e A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATEADD'. This is not supported.

Comment: I updated the dax formula in my answer to use the DATE() function instead of DATEADD(). Hope this helps